# Minimum payment criterion for credit cards

Tags: united-states, credit-card, minimum-payment

Is there a different policy that bank practice in generating minimum payment for a credit card balance? I have two credit cards with 0% interest APR going on both of them. I have similar credit card balance ( say for example X) on both the credit cards. One Bank is charging me 1% of X as the minimum payment and other bank is charging me 3% of X. I am in California. Does anyone know if there is a fixed / general rule in determining minimum balance for the customers?

Answer (score 6):

Entirely up to the bank and may be different for different customers. If it bothers you, shop around for a better offer.

Personally I believe that nobody should ***ever*** be making only the minimum payment, so I would ignore that number.

Comment: It's not completely up to the bank since there is some regulation, but this answer is basically correct. (Especially the part about it being a bad idea to make just the min payment.)  At the link here, there's some information about the regulation and also a survey of fees from a few banks. http://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/minimum-credit-card-payments-1267.php